# Android - Up navigation in ActionBar on ICS

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Up navigation in the Action Bar is simple to setup and works correctly on Jelly Bean:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and for that activity in the AndroidManifest

```
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
```

but the attribute `android:parentActivityName` is not available on ICS (4.0.3). The Android documentation is very vague on how to use it on ICS, says

> To support older devices with the support library, also include a <meta-data> element that specifies the parent activity as the value for android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY.

...which I did, but what is this about the support library? I followed the Support Library setup guide on http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html but... it still doesn't make the damn up button work in my app on ICS. It's such a small thing, why does it have to be so insanely complicated?

Comment: Are you using getSupportActionBar() insteed of getActionBar() while you are using the support library?

Comment: No, it says `The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type SecondActivity`

Comment: My bad. This is only available in the SherlockActionBar Library.

Answer (score 0):

You're extending `Activity` instead of `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`.

Then use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem as well, and wound up with a slightly different solution.

On each screen in my app, I inflate a menu, even if there are no menu options on that screen:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

The code above sets up a menu, but never inflates one.

I then explicitly set the up navigation to point to a specific class. Note the use of android.R.id.home:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    Intent i = null;

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            i = new Intent(getActivity(), DesiredActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have tested this on Android version 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.4.2 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what NKijak answered.

Another way to do this is to handle the Up action manually in the Child Activity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ParentActivity.class)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP));
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And best part of this manual approach is that it works as expected(resumes the ParentActivity instead of ReCreating it) for all API Levels.